# Export a nested displaytag table in excel

Tags: struts2, export-to-excel, displaytag

I have displayed a nested table using display tag .
The code of my nested table is:

```
<display:table export="true" name="detailsList" id="parent" requestURI="" pagesize="1">

    <display:column property="testcaseName"  />
    <display:column property="subject"  />
    <display:column property="description"  title="Comments" />

    <c:set var="nestedName"
        value="detailsList[${parent_rowNum -1}].testList" />


    <display:column title="TestCase Details" >


        <display:table name="${nestedName}" id="child${parent_rowNum}"
            class="SimpleSublist">

            <display:column property="stepName" />
            <display:column property="description" />
            <display:column property="inputField" />
            <display:column property="inputData" />
            <display:column property="expectedResult" />
            <display:column property="remarks" />

        </display:table>

    </display:column>

</display:table>
```

I wanted to have the export option for the same...
But I am not able to figure out how to do it..
Is there any workaround as the inbuilt export does not work here..

Answer (score 0):

Which in-built export are you talking about? If you want to export something to excel, you will have to do it programatically using libs like [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) [I have used it and found it great] and its [examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

**UPDATE:**

I googled and found this [display tag link](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/example-nestedtables.jsp) which says that nested tables cannot be exported by display tag :( (*check the last line of limitations*)

So the solution suggested above will work for you..